# Generate tests based on the result of a promise in Jest JS

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Right now I have a `simple.test.js` file that generates calls to `test` based on simplified call/response files (so we don't need to write a `.test.js` for each of these simplified cases). For reference I'll include the file here:

```
'use strict';

const api = require('./api');

const SCRIPT_NAME_KEY = Symbol('script name key'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');

const generateTests = (dir) => {
    const relPath = path.relative(__dirname, dir);
    let query, resultScripts = [], resultSqls = [];
    for (let entry of fs.readdirSync(dir)) {
        if (entry[0] === '-')
            continue;
        let fqEntry = path.join(dir, entry);
        if (fs.statSync(fqEntry).isDirectory()) {
            generateTests(fqEntry);
            continue;
        }
        if (entry === 'query.json')
            query = fqEntry;
        else if (entry.endsWith('.sql'))
            resultSqls.push(fqEntry);
        else if (entry.endsWith('.js') && !entry.endsWith('.test.js'))
            resultScripts.push(fqEntry);
    }
    if (!query && resultScripts.length === 0 && resultSqls.length === 0)
        return;
    if (!query)
        throw `${relPath} contains result script(s)/sql(s) but no query.json`;
    if (resultScripts.length === 0 && resultSqls.length === 0)
        throw `${relPath} contains a query.json file but no result script(s)/sql(s)`;

    try {
        query = require(query);
    } catch (ex) {
        throw `${relPath} query.json could not be parsed`;
    }

    for (let x = 0; x < resultScripts.length; x++) {
        let scriptName = path.basename(resultScripts[x]);
        console.log('scriptName', scriptName);
        try {
            resultScripts[x] = require(resultScripts[x]);
        } catch (ex) {
            throw `${relPath} result script ${scriptName} could not be parsed`;
        }
        resultScripts[x][SCRIPT_NAME_KEY] = scriptName;
    }

    test(`ST:${relPath}`, () => api.getSqls(query).then(resp => {
        if (resultScripts.length === 0) {
            expect(resp.err).toBeFalsy();
            expect(resp.data).toBeAllValidSql();
        } else {
            for (const script of resultScripts)
                expect({ n: script[SCRIPT_NAME_KEY], r: script(resp, script[SCRIPT_NAME_KEY]) }).toPass();
        }

        for (const sql of resultSqls)
            expect(resp.data).toIncludeSql(fs.readFileSync(sql, 'utf8'));
    }));
};

expect.extend({
    toPass(actual) {
        const pass = actual.r === void 0 || actual.r === null || !!actual.r.pass;
        return {
            pass: pass,
            message: pass ? null : () => actual.r.message || `${actual.n} check failed!`
        }
    }
});

generateTests(path.join(__dirname, 'SimpleTests'));
```

This works really great! It runs immediately when the `.test.js` file is loaded by Jest and generates a test for each folder containing the valid files.

However, I now have a need to generate a test per record in a database. From what I can tell most of the available modules that provide DB functionality work on the premise of promises (and reasonably so!). So now I need to wait for a query to come back BEFORE I generate the tests.

This is what I'm trying:

```
'use strict';

const api = require('./api');

api.getAllReportsThroughSideChannel().then((reports) => {
    for (const report of reports) {
        test(`${report.Name} (${report.Id} - ${report.OwnerUsername})`, () => {
            // ...
        });
    }
});
```

However when I do this I get:

```
 FAIL  ./reports.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Your test suite must contain at least one test.

      at ../node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/TestScheduler.js:256:22
```

As one might expect, the promise gets created but doesn't get a chance to actually trigger the generation of tests until after Jest has already expected to receive a list of tests from the file.

One thing I considered was to have a test that itself is a promise that checks out all the reports, but then it would fail on the first `expect` that results in a failure, and we want to get a list of all reports that fail tests. What we really want is a separate test for each.

I guess ultimately the question I want to know is if it is possible for the *generation* of tests to be done via a promise (rather then the tests themselves).

There is a TON of resources for Jest out there, after searching I didn't find anything that applies to my question, so apologies if I just missed it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a few days of looking through docs, and code, it's looking more and more like this simply can not be done in Jest (or probably more correctly, it goes counter to Jest's testing philosophies).

As such, I have created a step prior to running the jest runtime proper, that simply downloads the results of the query to a file, then I use the file to synchronously generate the test cases.

I would LOVE it if someone can propose a better solution though.